# Rails console stops to output any text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have a rails application and I execute some queries in the `bin/rails console`.

Now when I was doing a query to output some data suddenly the output stopped being displayed.

I can then assign a variable a given value and entering the variable does not output the value I just assigned:

```
irb(main):001:0> Card.all.each do {|c| print("#{c.full_name}: #{c.id}/#{c.first_name}-#{c._lastname}")  }
irb(main):004:2> x = _
irb(main):005:2> x
irb(main):006:2> x = 3 
irb(main):007:2> x # I would assume to see the value '3'
irb(main):009:3> print("hello") # I would assume to see "hello" on the screen
irb(main):010:3>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usually happens because of dangling syntax. In your case you're using *both* `do ... end` and `{ ... }`, notably omitting the `end`.

The IRB parser will continue to take input until you put in an `end`, and only then will it run and/or emit an error.

The fix is to scratch out the `do`.

You want *either*:

```rb
Card.all.each do |c|
  ...
end
```

Or the inline style:

```rb
Card.all.each { |c| ... }
```